# Jython Connecting to Mysql Database Error

Tags: mysql, database-connection, jython

I have been solving a problem with MYSQL and Jython for the past two days.

I keep receiving the error:

> zxJDBC.DatabaseError: Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306? [SQLCode: 0]

I have tried out multiple solutions:

> 1.) Changing the port number of mysql
>
> 2.) Tried out variations of connection methods

However, none have worked so far.

My netstat shows that there is indeed a server running on port 3306 :

> 0.0.0.0 3306 c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe

My code goes as:

```
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
userInfo = {'user':'root', 'password':'', 'databaseName':'amda','serverName':'localhost','port':3306}
dbconnection = zxJDBC.connectx("org.gjt.mm.mysql.MysqlDataSource", **userInfo)
```

If you can, please help! Many thanks!

Comment: You jdbc connect driver is not latest, please go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ to download latest driver.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna go through this thread. 
[MySQL Forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,6448,6448#msg-6448)
It is a similar error